# Highcharts show two line series with same values

Tags: highcharts, series

I have series that may have same values region. For example from 2 till 7th in follows example:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }]
});
});
```

Highcharts shows only one of the lines, the other line is simple over lay by first. What is the best approach to show such situation. I was trying to find a option that will let those be drawn back to back like stack on each other, but stack is different chart. What are the best choice to still present it?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddlel link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st option**

You could use transparent colors for each series like that :

```
series: [
    {
        color:'rgba(255,0,0,.5)',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        color:'rgba(0,0,255,.5)',
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
    }
]
```

[Fiddle - Transparent colors](https://jsfiddle.net/ows8cubL/)

**2nd option**

Use different [line width](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.lineWidth). The first serie will always be in the back so you can make it larger and it will surround the second serie :

```
series: [{
    lineWidth:6,
    marker:{
        radius : 7
    },
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}, {
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}],
```

[Fiddle - Line width](https://jsfiddle.net/ows8cubL/1/)

**3rd option**

Using the `dashStyle` [API Doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.dashStyle) :

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}, {
    dashStyle: 'dot',
    data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
}],
```

[Fiddle - dashStyle](https://jsfiddle.net/ows8cubL/2/)